# equivalent of audioPlayer.isPlaying() in AudioKit

Tags: audiokit

I am using the AudioKit's AudioPlayer!.  My earlier version of the code had
audioPlayer.isPlaying flag to check if the player is still playing or paused/stopped. Now that **isPlaying** flag has been removed, can someone please guide me on what is the equivalent code?

thanks,
-Vittal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try isStarted

From AudioPlayer+Playback:

```
/// Synonym for isPlaying
public var isStarted: Bool { status == .playing }
```